# Trying to query rails database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to pull all orders from the database from two specific clients, everything I try in rails c gives me a error:

```
irb(main):008:0> clients = clients.find(name: "CLS_Trials")
NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
```

my schema is this

```
create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "sku_part"
    t.float    "postage_account"
    t.boolean  "accrue_fees"
    t.float    "pick_pack_per_unit"
    t.string   "logo_file_name"
    t.string   "logo_content_type"
    t.integer  "logo_file_size"
    t.datetime "logo_updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.boolean  "sub_admin"
    t.boolean  "static_shipping"
    t.float    "static_shipping_amount"
    t.datetime "invoice_stop"
    t.string   "street_address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.string   "primary_contact_name"
    t.float    "min_postage"
    t.float    "postage_threshold"
    t.integer  "pageviews_today"
    t.integer  "pageviews_yesterday"
    t.boolean  "using_analytics"
    t.string   "sites",                  default: [], array: true
    t.integer  "weather_degrees"
    t.string   "weather_status"
    t.float    "other_fees"
    t.string   "lime_light_user_name"
    t.string   "lime_light_password"
    t.boolean  "using_lime_light"
  end
```

and I know the data is there, any advice on how to properly pull all the orders for both my clients and export the data into a text file or exel?  Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
clients = Client.where(name: "CLS_Trials")
```

C is capital and remove trailing 's'.
Because the class name in ruby must have first character capital. And in Rails the model are  referenced by singular.

**EDIT:**

Or you can also use built in helper

```
clients = Client.find_by_name('CLS_Trials')
```

for any attribute of models you can find them by following

```
obj = Klass_name.find_by_attr_name(attr_value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! so now to pull all the orders from that client all I have to do is something like,

Comment: orders = Orders.all(external_Id: tracking:)